docker inter-container communication with bridge network: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
It's not so complicated but still I've been stuck with an unknown problem for quite a few days which is constantly refusing to be solved. :(
Basically, on a high-level, I did a fresh install of docker engine on Ubuntu VDI using this ref, add customized daemon configuration /etc/docker/daemon.json, create a user-defined network and lastly try to connect the containers from both using containers' hostname as well as containers' ip.

Host OS (Virtual Machine connecting through RDP)

$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   Focal

$ uname -a
Linux IXXXXXD001 5.4.0-177-generic #197-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 28 22:45:47 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


HOST Network Interfaces

    $ docker network ls
    NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
    31ad3a96c5cc   br-net    bridge    local
    83bfcacaf953   bridge    bridge    local
    969622e0a27b   host      host      local
    7dd1f34794f4   none      null      local
    
   $ ip addr
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether e2:d1:68:5c:b5:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.54.62.14/24 brd 10.54.62.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
           valid_lft 653308sec preferred_lft 653308sec
        inet6 fe80::5527:ec7:24a3:6325/64 scope link noprefixroute 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    39: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
        link/ether 02:42:fa:5c:8c:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    40: br-31ad3a96c5cc: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
        link/ether 02:42:89:b4:03:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-31ad3a96c5cc
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    56: veth16f5946@if55: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-31ad3a96c5cc state UP group default 
        link/ether 7e:a3:b9:fd:bc:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    58: veth2164bfb@if57: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-31ad3a96c5cc state UP group default 
        link/ether 46:d5:4e:63:14:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1


HOST iptables -L

$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere 


HOST iptables -S

$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o br-31ad3a96c5cc -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-31ad3a96c5cc -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-31ad3a96c5cc ! -o br-31ad3a96c5cc -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-31ad3a96c5cc -o br-31ad3a96c5cc -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-31ad3a96c5cc ! -o br-31ad3a96c5cc -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-31ad3a96c5cc -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN


HOST ip route

$ ip route
default via 10.54.62.254 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.54.62.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.54.62.14 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-31ad3a96c5cc proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 


Content of /etc/docker/daemon.json

$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "data-root" : "/opt/docker-data",
  "debug": true,
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-level": "debug",
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "20"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}


Details of Docker Ingine

$ docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    26.1.0
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.14.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.26.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 4
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 4
 Server Version: 26.1.0
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: e377cd56a71523140ca6ae87e30244719194a521
 runc version: v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-177-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 6
 Total Memory: 31.33GiB
 Name: IXXXXXX001
 ID: b8ca102c-8e16-4f87-a0bf-beb74cd6296f
 Docker Root Dir: /opt/docker-data
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 74
  Goroutines: 105
  System Time: 2024-04-25T00:27:48.270028804+03:00
  EventsListeners: 0
 Username: ghoshsayak
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support


Details of Docker Components

$ docker network create br-net

Create Containers:
$ docker run -d --hostname debugger --network br-net --name debugger ghoshsayak/local-docker-env:debugger-20240420

$ docker run -d --hostname sqlserver --network br-net --name sqlserver --env MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD='xxxxx' --env ACCEPT_EULA='Y' --env TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04

Container "debugger" and "sqlserver" is running properly.
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS      NAMES
be15cc347760   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU18-ubuntu-20.04   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   1433/tcp   sqlserver

9a908ca983c9   ghoshsayak/local-docker-env:debugger-20240420           "python3 /server.py"     About an hour ago   Up About an hour   5000/tcp   debugger


Preflight Network tests on "debugger" container

$ docker exec -it debugger /bin/bash
root@debugger:/# nc -v -l -p 5000
nc: Address already in use
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# hostname
debugger
root@debugger:/# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
55: eth0@if56: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.18.0.2/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# netstat -plntu | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:37411        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python3           
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# curl http://localhost:5000
Hostname: debugger
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# curl http://172.18.0.2:5000 -v
*   Trying 172.18.0.2:5000...
* Immediate connect fail for 172.18.0.2: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# curl http://debugger:5000 -v
*   Trying 172.18.0.2:5000...
* Immediate connect fail for 172.18.0.2: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# nslookup debugger
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   debugger
Address: 172.18.0.2

root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# nslookup sqlserver
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   sqlserver
Address: 172.18.0.3

root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# telnet 172.18.0.3 1433
Trying 172.18.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# telnet sqlserver 1433
Trying 172.18.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# ip route
default via 172.18.0.1 dev eth0 
172.18.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.2 
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# traceroute debugger
traceroute to debugger (172.18.0.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
send: Connection refused
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# traceroute 172.18.0.2
traceroute to 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
send: Connection refused
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# traceroute sqlserver
traceroute to sqlserver (172.18.0.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
send: Connection refused
root@debugger:/# 
root@debugger:/# traceroute 172.18.0.3
traceroute to 172.18.0.3 (172.18.0.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
send: Connection refused
root@debugger:/# 


Preflight Network tests on "sqlserver" container

SAME AS ABOVE BEHAVIOUR.

Moreover, there is no ufw or firewalld service is active.
So, I tried to provide as much as information possible.
And now hoping for someone who can really help me out with!
Thanks.
